# How to find out what form I just submitted in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I use the `$.post` function to submit an ajax request as such:

```
$('.typeAform').submit(function(){
    $.post('/home', { somevar : 'somevalue' }, function(){
         //do something with the original form
    });
    return false;
});
```

I'd like to identify my form after submission from the `$.post` callback so I can do something with it (i.e. change its background color, delete it, etc...).
Normally, I'd be able to call the form by its unique id that I know ahead of time, but here I don't have it - I am using a class for the form, not a single id.

Is there a way I can identify the form I just submitted without using a global variable (i.e. pass it to the callback somehow).

Thanks!

Comment: Is there more than one form with the class `typeAform`?

Comment: yeup, that's why it's a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Because the target of the `submit` event should always be the form itself, you could also use the `target` property of the `event` object, as in: `e.target`

```
$('.typeAform').submit(function( e ){
    $.post('http://apple.com', { somevar : 'somevalue' }, function(){
         // e.target references the form that was submitted.
         alert(e.target)
    });
    return false;
});​
```

If this gives you trouble, then there are other ways to avoid creating a variable if you don't want that.

---

Get the ID from the DOM element in the `.submit()`:

```
var id = this.id;
```

So it would be:

```
$('.typeAform').submit(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    $.post('/home', { somevar : 'somevalue' }, function(){
         //do something with the original form
         // Use the "id" here
    });
    return false;
});
```

Or if you want the form itself, just reference `this`.

```
$('.typeAform').submit(function(){
    var theForm = this;
    $.post('/home', { somevar : 'somevalue' }, function(){
         //do something with the original form
         // Use the "theForm" here
         alert( theForm.id );
         $(theForm).someJQueryMethod()
    });
    return false;
});
```

Note that once you're inside the `$.post` callback, `this` no longer references the `<form>`. That's why we referenced it in a variable.

Comment: is there no way to find out from within the $.post what form was just submitted without setting a variable beforehand? something like `$.post('/home', {...}, function(event)(){ alert(event.form); })` or a similar syntax?

Comment: @yuval - Sorry, I didn't see this comment until just now. Yes, you could use `e.target`, giving the `submit()` handler a parameter named `e`. This will give you the form that was submitted. Either way will work. In both methods, the value of `e` or `this` is evaluated when the `.sumbit()` handler fires. I'll update.

Comment: Be sure to use `e.srcElement` if `e.target` is undefined for IE compatibility.

Comment: @Daniel - Not in this case. This is jQuery's `event` object which normalizes things such as the `target` property. See the *event properties* section here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/